# How to Save File with time as name and return time value with uploadify

Tags: ajax, uploadify

what i intend to do, is to use uploadify to upload a file, change its name in uploadify.php for the value of time() ,save it , and return the name of the saved file back to the HTML, im not sure how to do it, currently im using this as guide

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/customizing-the-server-side-upload-script/

and this is my code so far

index.php

```
'<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"      
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.uploadify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
      'name'     : 'somename'  
            },
    'method' : 'post',
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
             onUploadComplete : function(data, file , response){
  alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
  alert(response);

            }           
        });
    }); 

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
        var img = 'localhost/uploads/'+ $("#hidden").val;
        var cuenta_sap =  $("#cuenta_sap").val(); 
        var ubicacion =  $("#ubicacion").val(); 
        var codigo_centro_beneficio =  $("#codigo_centro_beneficio").val(); 
        var nombre =  $("#nombre").val(); 
        var proyecto = $ ("#proyecto").val();
        var departamento = $ ("#departamento").val();
        var tipo_activo = $("#tipo_activo").val();
        var proveedor = $("#proveedor").val();
        var modelo = $("#modelo").val();
        var numero_serie = $("#numero_serie").val();
        var marca = $ ("#marca").val();
        var numero_remision = $("#numero_remision").val();
        var myData ='cuenta_sap='+ cuenta_sap + '&ubicacion='+ ubicacion + 
       '&codigo_centro_beneficio='+ codigo_centro_beneficio + '&nombre=' + nombre + '&proyecto='    
        + proyecto + '&departamento='+ departamento + '&tipo_activo=' + tipo_activo 
      +'&proveedor='+ proveedor +'&modelo=' + modelo + '&numero_serie=' + numero_serie +'&marca='    
       + marca + '&numero_remision='+ numero_remision;

  e.preventDefault();


           if(cuenta_sap==''||ubicacion==''||codigo_centro_beneficio==''
           ||nombre==''||proyecto==''||departamento
            ==''||tipo_activo==''||proveedor==''||modelo==''
           ||numero_serie==''||marca==''||numero_remision=='')
  {
    alert("Formato incompleto!");
    return false;
  }

  $("#FormSubmit").hide(); //hide submit button
  $("#LoadingImage").show(); //show loading image

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
  url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
  dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
  data:myData, //
  success:function(result){

     $("#responds").delay(10000).fadeIn();
    $("#responds").append("<li class='res'>"+result+"</li>");
          $('.res').remove();
          $("#proyecto").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#departamento").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#tipo_activo").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#modelo").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#numero_serie").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#marca").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#numero_remision").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#cuenta_sap").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#ubicacion").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#nombre").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#codigo_centro_beneficio").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
    $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
    $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image
    alert(thrownError);
  }
  });
  });

$("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split ID string (Split works as PHP explode)
 var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
 var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

 $('#item_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); //change background of this element by adding class
 $(this).hide(); //hide currently clicked delete button

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
  url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
  dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
  data:myData, //Form variables
  success:function(response){
    //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
    $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    //On error, we alert user
    alert(thrownError);
  }
  });
});

});
</script>
<div class="content_wrapper" id="wrapepr">
<div class="form_style">
<input name="hidden" id="hidden" type="text"></input>
<br>
<a>Datos</a>
<br>
<input name="cuenta_sap" id="cuenta_sap" placeholder="cuenta sap" class="input"></input>

<select name="departamento" class="input" id="departamento">
<option value = "">seleccione departamento</option>
<?php
include("db.php");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `departamento` FROM `departamentos`");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$departamento);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
echo "<option value='$id'>$departamento</option>";
}
?>
  </select>  
  <select name="proyecto" class="input" id="proyecto" >
<option value = "" >seleccione proyecto</option>
<?php

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` ,`proyecto` FROM `proyectos`");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$proyecto);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
echo "<option value='$id'>$proyecto</option>";
}
?>
  </select>  
  <select name="tipo" class="input" id="tipo_activo">
<option value = "" class="input" >tipo de activo</option>
<?php

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` ,`tipo` FROM `tipo_activo`");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$tipo_activo);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
echo "<option value='$id' class='input'>$tipo_activo</option>";
}
?>
  </select>  
    <select name="proveedor" class="input" id="proveedor">
<option value = "" class="input" >seleccione proveedor</option>
<?php

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` ,`nombre` FROM `proveedores`");
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($id,$nombre);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
echo "<option value='$id' class='input'>$nombre</option>";
}
?>
  </select>  
<input name="codigo_centro_beneficio" id="codigo_centro_beneficio"  placeholder="codigo centro      
  beneficio" class="input"></input>

<input name="nombre" id="nombre"  placeholder="nombre"  class="input"></input>

 <input name="modelo" id="modelo"  placeholder="modelo"  class="input"></input>

  <input name="numero_serie" id="numero_serie"  placeholder="numero_serie"  class="input">    
 </input>

   <input name="marca" id="marca"  placeholder="marca"  class="input"></input>

<input name="numero_remision" id="numero_remision" placeholder="numero remision" class="input">       
</input>

<input name="upload" id="upload" class="input" type="file"></input>
<button id="FormSubmit">registrar</button>

<img src="images/loading.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
</div>
<ul id="responds" >

</ul> 
</div>

</body>
</html>'
```

and uploadify.php
   '

```
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$now = time();
$name = $_POST('name')FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;


// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $now .'.'. $fileParts['extension'];
echo rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $now .'.'. $fileParts['extension'];
if(file_exists($targetFile)){
    ++$now;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $now .'.'. $fileParts['extension'];
      $name $targetPath,'/') . '/' . $now .'.'. $fileParts['extension'];
      echo $name;

      }


if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {

  move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

} 
else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';


}
?>'
```

Comment: index.html should be renamed to index.php, because it contains php tag.

Comment: my bad it is actually index.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this, after a while of searching and reading uploadify manuals, it turns out if you use onUploadComplete, and you just upload one single fine, the method will never excecute, and it will keep waiting for more files, instead for one file only, you have to use onUploadSuccess, and read the data returned  by it using file,data,response as parameters.